# Solve $y+3=3\sqrt{(y+7)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $y+3=3\sqrt{(y+7)^2}$

$\Rightarrow y+3=3(y+7)$

$\Rightarrow y+3=3y+21$

$\Rightarrow 2y=-18$

$y=-9$

But $-9+3\ne3\sqrt{(-9+7)^2} \Rightarrow-6 \ne6$

How is this humanely possible? What's going on here???

Comment: Hint : Don't skip the "first step" that you don't bring up and use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$

Comment: "How is this humanely possible?"  It isn't.    "What's going on here???" Just because someone asks you a question doesn't mean there is an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sqrt{a^2}$ is not equal to $a$, it’s equal to $|a|$. So

$$y+3=3\sqrt{(y+7)^2}$$

$$y+3=3|y+7|$$

We see that $y+3\ge0$, so $y+7>0$, and $|y+7|=y+7$.

$$y+3=3(y+7)$$

$$2y=-18$$

$$y=-9$$

But $y+3\ge0$ doesn’t hold. Hence, no solutions.

Comment: How do you know $y+3>0$? At that point $y$ could be anything.

Comment: $y+3=3|y+7|$ so that the RHS is $\geq 0$, and hence must be the LHS.

Comment: Because it is equal to a (tripled) square root, which can’t be negative. So no, $y$ can’t be anything

Comment: From $y+3=3|y+7|$, we know both sides must be positive because there is an absolute value, and by definition it is positive. But then when you solve for $y+3=3(y+7)$ you get $y=-9$, which means $y+3=-6$. So this contradiction means this problem has no solutions? Or in other words this equation makes no sense and is illogical and wrong?

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson This equation is logical and not wrong. It just happens to have no solutions. For example. $x^2=4$ has solutions $x=\pm2$. But $x^2=-4$ doesn’t have solutions (in real numbers). It doesn’t make this equation “worse” in any sense.

Comment: To nitpick we do *not* know $y+3 > 0$ we know that $3\sqrt{(y+7)^2}\ge 0$ so $y+3\ge 0$.  But $y+7 =(y+3)+4 > (y+3)+0=y+3 =3\sqrt{(y+7)^2}$ so $y+7 > 0$.  "not negative" $\ne$ "positive".

Comment: @fleablood I’ve edited $>$ to $\ge$.

Comment: I *did* say I was nitpicking....

Answer (score 0):

When we say "solve $y+3=3\sqrt{(y+7)^2}$", we mean "find the set $S$ of solutions",ie$$S:=\{y\in \mathbb R: y+3=3\sqrt{(y+7)^2} \}$$
We don't know this set, because we're looking for it. With practice, we learn that this set can be empty, have only one solution, or several, or even infinity. So we get cautious and we start by writing:

Let $ y\in S$. $\color{red}{\text{Then}}$, by squaring, $$(y+3)^2=9(y+7)^2$$

$\color{red}{\text{Then}}$, by using $\forall a,b \in \mathbb R, a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, we obtain $$[y+3-3(y+7)][y+3+3(y+7)]=0$$

$\color{red}{\text{Then}}, -8(y+9)(y+6)=0$

$\color{red}{\text{Then}}, \begin{cases}y=-9 \\\text{or}\\ y=-6 \end{cases}$

So the only two possible solutions are $-6$ and $-9$. What we write $$S\subset \{-6,-9\}$$

But since we've been working $\color{red}{\text{by implications}}$, we still need to check that they're suitable. Neither is suitable. So, don't panic, it happens, there's no solution. What We Write $$S=\emptyset$$ the empty set.

Comment: Why did you square both sides when you can just remove the square root on the right side, and I don't understand how you ended up with values for $y$ but neither works in the original equation. How can you derive a solution that does not work? That's a contradiction.

Comment: @Aig explained why you can't just remove the square root. If you are French, then you are a European. But all European are not necessarly French.  If $y$ is a solution of your equation, then $y$ is necessarly $-6$ or $-9$ but neither $-6$ , $-9$ are solutions, as you saw.

Comment: "How can you derive a solution that does not work? " The poster didn't do any such thing.  The very first sentence was that "solve" means to find the *set* of all possible solutions.  The poster did exactly that.  The poster found there are *no* possible solution to the equation.  So to *set of all possible solutions* is the empty set.  The solution to the *question* is:  There are no solutions to the *equation*.   If I asked you "Who was the third woman president of the United States in the year 1563?" the answer is: There wasn't any.  That's not a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

The error that you have is very subtle. If you do not make any simplifications, the right-hand side of the equation will never be negative, that is because $\sqrt{(x+7)^2} = |x+7|$. So actually you have a different equation that doesn't have solutions (you can check it with simple algebra)